# How to get the address associated to a label at linking stage?

Tags: assembly, compilation, linker

I'm currently working at a custom loader program and, one of the operations I'm trying to achieve, is to modify some code before deploying it. 
Long story short, I have a ASM file containing different labels:

```
MOD1:
    MOV add,add
    POP add
    ....
MOD2:
    other assembly
```

and what I want to know is the address with which each label (*MOD1, MOD2,...*) has been replaced (e.g. *MOD1=0x4400*). I need this info before deploying the image, so that I can embed it in the elf file itself; however, I don't have any clue on how to extract such information from the linker files.
Would you be able to point me in the right direction? I have full control on the compiling chain, so I can operate at any level.
**Thank you**

Comment: You can use the `nm` utility to dump the symbol table of the linked binary.  This contains the values (i.e. the addresses) of all symbols.  I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve; sounds a bit contrived and you might be suffering from the XY problem.

Comment: If you want to update it at runtime from within the program, just make the label global and reference it from the file where you want to use it.  I don't see how you need external tooling for that.